# Symfony baseUrl doesn't respond to apache rewrites and breaks all routes

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony

Imagine yourself a simple symfony install:

```
symfony new testsite
```

Now imagine this is inside the webroot of an apache server. Of course this won't work since the symfony webroot is in the `/web/` folder.

So you make a simple rewriterule and drop it in a htaccess in the symfony folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [QSA,L]
```

And this works. Hooray! So you try out the "[Create your first page in symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/page_creation.html)" guide and lo and behold your controller's 404ing!

[image]

So it seems like symfony is cutting off 3 characters from the start of the path. A bit of debugging shows it's getting the base url from the `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` which is the cause of the problem, since this doesn't change when you rewrite the url.

Is there a proper way to fix this or do I just have to redefine `SCRIPT_NAME` manually in my app.php?

Comment: Can you edit your post and post your 'exact' code please? It's probably something simple.

Comment: It's so simple I literally copy pasted their example (With a PHP open tag of course) The only code here I actually wrote is the htaccess file which is right there. No matter how much I search it looks like symfony is pretty much never run directly from a webroot (Which is weird since it seems a common use case)

Comment: So do you have the `web/` folder as the Apache DocumentRoot? It would be nice if you posted your Apache VirtualDirectory config or config, just in case you've missed something. I'm only trying to help.

Comment: No, I specifically said the entire symfony install was inside the webroot. But it turns out it's a known bug in symfony (14064), and I'm going to submit a PR to fix it

Answer (score 1):

if you comments are correct, then the URL you should be using is:

```
symfony-test.local/web/app_dev.php/lucky/number
```

You should specify the DocumentRoot as the `web/` folder! That is normally what is done. Read this for more details:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html